# R: Linear Regression with N Features

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I saw quite a few examples of how to do regression (linear, multiple... etc.) but on every example I saw, you had to define every single feature in the formula...

```
linearMod <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ..., data=myData)
```

Well, we used TSFresh to generate more features. Around 100. So how am I supposed to do this now? I don't really want to type in x1 .. all the way to .. x100. 
In Phyton scikit-learn I could just put in all the data:

```
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X,y)
```

And then repeat this for each 'feature group' to create a multiple linear regression.

Is there a way to do this in R? Or am I doing it wrong? Maybe another approach?

Originally we had 8 features/properties per Row. And with TSFresh we gernerated more of those. (Mean, STD and so on)

And every one of those features has a pretty linear influence on the Y result. So how can I now define something like a multiple linear model that just uses all extended features? Ideally without me having to tell it by hand each time.

So for example (one formulare would probably be feature 1-12 for Y) the next one (13-24 for Y) and so on. Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to regress on all variables except `Y` you can do

```
lm(Y ~ ., data = myData)
```

Comment: I tried it and then I got: error in model.frame.default(formula = diff ~ ., data = data_for_prediction, : Object is not a matrix. (I'm using a dataframe, might this be a problem?

Comment: data_for_prediction <- route[,c(7,13:668)]
  
fit <- lm(data_for_prediction[,1] ~ as.matrix(data_for_prediction[,-1]), data = data_for_prediction)  

  Error... invalid type (list) for the variable 'data_for_prediction[,1]'... I has honestly no clue what this thing wants from me

Comment: As an example, consider the dataframe `mtcars`: `lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)`.
In the output you see that every variable *except* `mpg` is used as independent variables in the regression.
I can't really give more specific feedback without knowing your data.